# how to get list of supported encodings by iconv library in php?

Tags: php, iconv

Is it possible like in the mcrypt library with function `mcrypt_list_algorithms()`. Is there a iconv_list_encodings like function ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In PHP the [`iconv` extension](http://php.net/iconv) does not have a function to list all available encodings.

The encodings which are available depends on which library `iconv` internally uses. For example there is [**libiconv**](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/). That website also contains a list of charsets you can use.

You can also connect to your server via SSH and execute the following command:

```
$ iconv -l
```

This will give you the available list on that system if PHP is compiled against the same library as the command-line utility.

If you're uncertain if a specific charset is available, you need to check for errors by probing with [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

---

List of iconv encoding and aliases (Feb 2013; [gist](https://gist.github.com/4188459)):

```
ANSI_X3.4-1968 ANSI_X3.4-1986 ASCII CP367 IBM367 ISO-IR-6 ISO646-US ISO_646.IRV:1991 US US-ASCII CSASCII
UTF-8
ISO-10646-UCS-2 UCS-2 CSUNICODE
UCS-2BE UNICODE-1-1 UNICODEBIG CSUNICODE11
UCS-2LE UNICODELITTLE
ISO-10646-UCS-4 UCS-4 CSUCS4
UCS-4BE
UCS-4LE
UTF-16
UTF-16BE
UTF-16LE
UTF-32
UTF-32BE
UTF-32LE
UNICODE-1-1-UTF-7 UTF-7 CSUNICODE11UTF7
UCS-2-INTERNAL
UCS-2-SWAPPED
UCS-4-INTERNAL
UCS-4-SWAPPED
C99
JAVA
CP819 IBM819 ISO-8859-1 ISO-IR-100 ISO8859-1 ISO_8859-1 ISO_8859-1:1987 L1 LATIN1 CSISOLATIN1
ISO-8859-2 ISO-IR-101 ISO8859-2 ISO_8859-2 ISO_8859-2:1987 L2 LATIN2 CSISOLATIN2
ISO-8859-3 ISO-IR-109 ISO8859-3 ISO_8859-3 ISO_8859-3:1988 L3 LATIN3 CSISOLATIN3
ISO-8859-4 ISO-IR-110 ISO8859-4 ISO_8859-4 ISO_8859-4:1988 L4 LATIN4 CSISOLATIN4
CYRILLIC ISO-8859-5 ISO-IR-144 ISO8859-5 ISO_8859-5 ISO_8859-5:1988 CSISOLATINCYRILLIC
ARABIC ASMO-708 ECMA-114 ISO-8859-6 ISO-IR-127 ISO8859-6 ISO_8859-6 ISO_8859-6:1987 CSISOLATINARABIC
ECMA-118 ELOT_928 GREEK GREEK8 ISO-8859-7 ISO-IR-126 ISO8859-7 ISO_8859-7 ISO_8859-7:1987 ISO_8859-7:2003 CSISOLATINGREEK
HEBREW ISO-8859-8 ISO-IR-138 ISO8859-8 ISO_8859-8 ISO_8859-8:1988 CSISOLATINHEBREW
ISO-8859-9 ISO-IR-148 ISO8859-9 ISO_8859-9 ISO_8859-9:1989 L5 LATIN5 CSISOLATIN5
ISO-8859-10 ISO-IR-157 ISO8859-10 ISO_8859-10 ISO_8859-10:1992 L6 LATIN6 CSISOLATIN6
ISO-8859-11 ISO8859-11 ISO_8859-11
ISO-8859-13 ISO-IR-179 ISO8859-13 ISO_8859-13 L7 LATIN7
ISO-8859-14 ISO-CELTIC ISO-IR-199 ISO8859-14 ISO_8859-14 ISO_8859-14:1998 L8 LATIN8
ISO-8859-15 ISO-IR-203 ISO8859-15 ISO_8859-15 ISO_8859-15:1998 LATIN-9
ISO-8859-16 ISO-IR-226 ISO8859-16 ISO_8859-16 ISO_8859-16:2001 L10 LATIN10
KOI8-R CSKOI8R
KOI8-U
KOI8-RU
CP1250 MS-EE WINDOWS-1250
CP1251 MS-CYRL WINDOWS-1251
CP1252 MS-ANSI WINDOWS-1252
CP1253 MS-GREEK WINDOWS-1253
CP1254 MS-TURK WINDOWS-1254
CP1255 MS-HEBR WINDOWS-1255
CP1256 MS-ARAB WINDOWS-1256
CP1257 WINBALTRIM WINDOWS-1257
CP1258 WINDOWS-1258
850 CP850 IBM850 CSPC850MULTILINGUAL
862 CP862 IBM862 CSPC862LATINHEBREW
866 CP866 IBM866 CSIBM866
MAC MACINTOSH MACROMAN CSMACINTOSH
MACCENTRALEUROPE
MACICELAND
MACCROATIAN
MACROMANIA
MACCYRILLIC
MACUKRAINE
MACGREEK
MACTURKISH
MACHEBREW
MACARABIC
MACTHAI
HP-ROMAN8 R8 ROMAN8 CSHPROMAN8
NEXTSTEP
ARMSCII-8
GEORGIAN-ACADEMY
GEORGIAN-PS
KOI8-T
CP154 CYRILLIC-ASIAN PT154 PTCP154 CSPTCP154
KZ-1048 RK1048 STRK1048-2002 CSKZ1048
MULELAO-1
CP1133 IBM-CP1133
ISO-IR-166 TIS-620 TIS620 TIS620-0 TIS620.2529-1 TIS620.2533-0 TIS620.2533-1
CP874 WINDOWS-874
VISCII VISCII1.1-1 CSVISCII
TCVN TCVN-5712 TCVN5712-1 TCVN5712-1:1993
ISO-IR-14 ISO646-JP JIS_C6220-1969-RO JP CSISO14JISC6220RO
JISX0201-1976 JIS_X0201 X0201 CSHALFWIDTHKATAKANA
ISO-IR-87 JIS0208 JIS_C6226-1983 JIS_X0208 JIS_X0208-1983 JIS_X0208-1990 X0208 CSISO87JISX0208
ISO-IR-159 JIS_X0212 JIS_X0212-1990 JIS_X0212.1990-0 X0212 CSISO159JISX02121990
CN GB_1988-80 ISO-IR-57 ISO646-CN CSISO57GB1988
CHINESE GB_2312-80 ISO-IR-58 CSISO58GB231280
CN-GB-ISOIR165 ISO-IR-165
ISO-IR-149 KOREAN KSC_5601 KS_C_5601-1987 KS_C_5601-1989 CSKSC56011987
EUC-JP EUCJP EXTENDED_UNIX_CODE_PACKED_FORMAT_FOR_JAPANESE CSEUCPKDFMTJAPANESE
MS_KANJI SHIFT-JIS SHIFT_JIS SJIS CSSHIFTJIS
CP932
ISO-2022-JP CSISO2022JP
ISO-2022-JP-1
ISO-2022-JP-2 CSISO2022JP2
CN-GB EUC-CN EUCCN GB2312 CSGB2312
GBK
CP936 MS936 WINDOWS-936
GB18030
ISO-2022-CN CSISO2022CN
ISO-2022-CN-EXT
HZ HZ-GB-2312
EUC-TW EUCTW CSEUCTW
BIG-5 BIG-FIVE BIG5 BIGFIVE CN-BIG5 CSBIG5
CP950
BIG5-HKSCS:1999
BIG5-HKSCS:2001
BIG5-HKSCS BIG5-HKSCS:2004 BIG5HKSCS
EUC-KR EUCKR CSEUCKR
CP949 UHC
CP1361 JOHAB
ISO-2022-KR CSISO2022KR
CP856
CP922
CP943
CP1046
CP1124
CP1129
CP1161 IBM-1161 IBM1161 CSIBM1161
CP1162 IBM-1162 IBM1162 CSIBM1162
CP1163 IBM-1163 IBM1163 CSIBM1163
DEC-KANJI
DEC-HANYU
437 CP437 IBM437 CS
PC8CODEPAGE437
CP737
CP775 IBM775 CSPC775BALTIC
852 CP852 IBM852 CSPCP852
CP853
855 CP855 IBM855 CSIBM855
857 CP857 IBM857 CSIBM857
CP858
860 CP860 IBM860 CSIBM860
861 CP-IS CP861 IBM861 CSIBM861
863 CP863 IBM863 CSIBM863
CP864 IBM864 CSIBM864
865 CP865 IBM865 CSIBM865
869 CP-GR CP869 IBM869 CSIBM869
CP1125
EUC-JISX0213
SHIFT_JISX0213
ISO-2022-JP-3
BIG5-2003
ISO-IR-230 TDS565
ATARI ATARIST
RISCOS-LATIN1
```

Comment: and how to do this on windows?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses: If you've got iconv installed on windows, you can get  the exact listing, too with the same command. I put such a created list here: https://gist.github.com/4188459

Comment: yeah :/ but I only got the extension in PHP, but thanks for the list :D its really helpful

Comment: try to install iconv with cygwin, it may be possible as you can see here https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flibiconv%2Flibiconv-1.14-2&grep=iconv.h

Answer (score 2):

If using GLIBC's iconv, the list of encodings and aliases is usually in:

```
/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules
```

If using Debian multiarch, it will instead be in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules
```

Note that aliases for `ASCII`, `UTF-8`, `UTF-16BE`, `UTF-16LE`, `UTF-32BE`, and `UTF-32LE` are not listed there.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, in PHP the [`iconv` extension](http://php.net/iconv) does not have a function to list all available encodings.

The command line, however, does have such an option. This can be used to create the function you're looking for:

```php
function iconv_list_encodings() {
   return preg_split('#//\n#', shell_exec('iconv -l'), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/JSUy).