# About PHP XMLwriter() encoding input and output

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, xmlwriter

I've been looking everywhere for a detailed explanation on how the XMLWriter() encodes its output but couldn't find it. I would like to know what encoding should the input data be in if I want an specific output encoding, for example ISO-8859-1. Should I give it the input data in the same format?

For example here:

```
$xw->writeElement('garantie','Garantie à vie'); *edited
$xw->endElement();
```

Should I do any encoding conversion on the string 'Garantie à vie' or does the `XMLWriter()` convert it automatically? Should the string be in ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I do any encoding conversion on the string 'Garantie à vie' or does the XMLWriter() convert it automatically?

`XMLWriter` accepts UTF-8 string input in PHP and it will automatically re-encode it into the output encoding (if needed). This internal re-encoding is not always needed because an XML's default default encoding is UTF-8 already.

> Should the string be in ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8?

The string should be UTF-8 encoded.

Example (with an UTF-8 encoded string; [Demo](https://eval.in/51120)):

```
<?php
/**
 * About PHP XMLwriter() encoding input and output
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046825/367456
 * @link https://eval.in/51120
 */

$xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
$xmlWriter->openMemory();
$xmlWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'US-ASCII');
$xmlWriter->writeElement('garantie', 'Garantie à vie');
$xmlWriter->endDocument();
echo $xmlWriter->flush();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<garantie>Garantie &#224; vie</garantie>
```

See as well:

- [A more detailed explanation of XMLWriter character set encodings can be found in an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18891201/367456) which was answering the *"php XML export issue with XMLWriter using writeAttribute() method"* question. It also explains how to change the encoding of the output document.
- The question [*How to check if string is a valid XML element name?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2519845/367456) covers the topic of valid element names in PHP (UTF-8 encoded and other) quite well.

Comment: Sorry, it should say: 

$xw->writeElement('garantie','Garantie à vie');

So, if I understand correctly, it is enough to make sure the text 'Garantie à vie' is in UTF-8 and then the XMLWriter output will be in the encoding I set? For example: 
$xw->startDocument('1.0','ISO-8859-1');

Comment: @Pato: Yes, exactly that way. The second parameter containing `'ISO-8859-1'` can be upper or lower case (it's common to use upper-case). The character-encoding-names which can be used depend on your PHP configuration, `ISO-8859-1` should not pose any problems.

Comment: And while commenting that: The demo site I linked *does not support ISO-8859-1* - don't ask me why :D Never experienced that before, but as written, this depends on PHP configuration.