# Debug iconv_strlen error - PHP 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, iconv, mbstring

I am trying to export a document to PDF using Laravel & DomPDF. This works on my mac, but not on staging or live server. Error as follows:

I have no idea what this means, and cannot find any solutions.

`iconv_strlen(): Wrong charset, conversion from`8bit//IGNORE' to `UCS-4LE' is not allowed`

```
open: /srv/www/html/vendor/patchwork/utf8/class/Patchwork/PHP/Shim/Mbstring.php

        return true;
    }

    static function mb_strlen($s, $encoding = INF)
    {
        INF === $encoding && $encoding = self::$internal_encoding;
        return iconv_strlen($s, $encoding . '//IGNORE');
    }
```

I have tried adding the following to .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

I have tried adding the following to the top of the view which I am trying to generate the pdf for:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

If you need any further information to assist me in debugging, please ask in comments.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in the MBString compatiblity shim supplied by Patchwork. I.e. your server does not have MBString enabled and something in the shim doesn't quite work as expected. It would help to know what's calling the `mb_strlen` function.  Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks BrianS. Problem solved by re-installing mbstring. `sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi*" install php-mbstring*
sudo httpd -k restart`

Comment: ^^ You should make this a solution by answering your own question. Can you also explain how you run this process.

Comment: @Gravy I had the same problem, and updating php-mbstring here resolved it.  You should post an answer to your question with what you did to resolve it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks BrianS.

This was solved by re-installing mbstring.

```
sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi*"
install php-mbstring*
sudo httpd -k restart
```

Answer (score 4):

BrianS's solution does indeed solve the issue, but I thought it'd be interesting to explain what caused the original problem.

In the [latest release of dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1),
the [`Cpdf`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/c3527d98d03e61847bd25f9e5cedf86dcc46bebf/lib/class.pdf.php) class
contains about 30 calls to `mb_strlen()` with the `$encoding` parameter set to `'8bit'`, which is a
[valid encoding for `mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mbstring.supported-encodings).

Laravel's [`composer.json`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/composer.json)
requires [`patchwork/utf8`](https://github.com/tchwork/utf8). It provides the `mb_strlen()` shim
which calls `iconv_strlen()`.

PHP usually uses either `glibc` or `libiconv` for its [`iconv`](http://php.net/intro.iconv) module.
For both libraries, the list of supported encodings can be
[displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8039232) using `iconv --list`.

Neither of those libraries support an encoding called `'8bit'`, which is why `iconv_strlen()`
throws that error:

```
Wrong charset, conversion from '8bit//IGNORE' to 'UCS-4LE' is not allowed
```

Installing the `mbstring` PHP module causes `mb_strlen()` to be executed natively,
so the shim isn't used and the error doesn't occur.

#### Update

@rofavadeka One solution is to create a
[fork](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/fork) of the
[dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) repo, and replace every use of
`'8bit'` encoding with a different 8-bit encoding which is supported by
`mb_strlen()`, `glibc` and `libiconv`.

I've written [a script](http://pastebin.com/Wz7m2Chz) to determine which encodings are suitable.
Here's the output of the script for
[`glibc`](http://pastebin.com/ZDmeRXNK) and
[`libiconv`](http://pastebin.com/fR2GqR48).
The suitable encodings are:

- [`cp850`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)
- [`cp866`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866)
- [`iso-8859-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
- [`iso-8859-2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2)
- [`iso-8859-4`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-4)
- [`iso-8859-5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5)
- [`iso-8859-9`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9)
- [`iso-8859-10`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-10)
- [`iso-8859-13`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-13)
- [`iso-8859-14`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-14)
- [`iso-8859-15`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)
- [`iso-8859-16`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16)
- [`koi8-r`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R)
- [`koi8-u`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-U)

Comment: So is there a way to change the '8bit' encoding or get around this problem? Having the samen problem, but on shared hosting, so sadly i can not simply reinstall to solve the issue! Hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting that error in `Hash:make()` during seeding my DB for testing.

Enabling `php_mbstring` in `php-cli.ini` caused it.

In Windows the solution is: remove the semicolon before

```
 extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

Comment: Do you mean, in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WHM then you can use EasyApache to rebuild.  Once you get the modules options after selecting your version of PHP select the "Exhaustive Options List" button.  Then ctrl+f "mbstring" and it should come up.  Mark the check box and rebuild.  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on wamp or some custom stack, remember that the `php` in your [wamp](/questions/tagged/wamp) may be using a custom `php_something.ini` for the apache use, due to which even if the [wamp](/questions/tagged/wamp) GUI is showing that `mbstring` is **on**(uncommented) still its quiet possible that that same line is commented out(disabled/**off**) inside the actual `php.ini` file (*True Story*).

**Solution**:-
Just navigate to

```
wamp dir > bin > php > phpx.x.x >
```

In this directory you shall find various `.ini` files named slightly differently, Mine was using `php_uwamp.ini` for the stack but for the `CLI`,  `php` was using the adjacent file named `php.ini`.

This had me pulling hairs for quiet long, thought it might help someone.