# PHP: UTF8_decode needed with filter for ASCII values 126-160; proposed solution

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, mb-convert-encoding

I previously began exploring this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466995/php-how-to-write-file-to-disk-with-unicode-characters). Here is the true problem, and a proposed solution:

Filenames with ASCII characters values between 32 and 255 pose a problem for utf8_encode(). Specifically, it doesn't handle the character values inclusively between 126 and 160 correctly. While filenames with those character names may be written to a database, passing those filenames to a function in PHP code will produce error messages stating the file cannot be found, etc.

I discovered this when trying to pass a filename with the offending characters to getimagesize().

What is needed for utf8_encode is a filter to EXCLUDE the conversion of the inclusive values between 126 and 160, while INCLUDING the conversion of all other characters (or any character, characters, or character ranges of the user's dersire; mine is for the ranges stated, for the reason provided).

The solution I devised requires two functions, listed below, and their application that follows:

```
// With thanks to Mark Baker for this function, posted elsewhere on StackOverflow
function _unichr($o) {
    if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
        return mb_convert_encoding('&#'.intval($o).';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    } else {
        return chr(intval($o));
    }
} 

// For each character where value is inclusively between 126 and 160, 
// write out the _unichr of the character, else write out the UTF8_encode of the character
function smart_utf8_encode($source) {
    $text_array = str_split($source, 1);
    $new_string = '';
    foreach ($text_array as $character) {
        $value = ord($character);
        if ((126 <= $value) && ($value <= 160)) {
            $new_string .= _unichr($character);
        } else {
            $new_string .= utf8_encode($character);
        }
    }
    return $new_string;
}

$file_name = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ.jpg";

// This MUST be done first:
$file_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252', $file_name);

// Next, smart_utf8_encode the variable (from encoding.inc.php):
$file_name = smart_utf8_encode($file_name);

// Now the file name may be passed to getimagesize(), etc.
$getimagesize = getimagesize($file_name);
```

If only PHP7 (6 is being skipped in the numbering, yes?) would include a filter on utf8_encode() to exclude certain character values, none of this would be necessary.

Comment: You are confusing bytes, characters, and encodings. The only sane way to expose a file system with a different character-set encoding is to URL-encode the raw bytes of the file name. But that's not really sane, either; the really sane solution is to have UTF-8 all the way

Comment: The `utf8_encode` function works exactly as specified: it takes a string encoded as `ISO_8859-1` and returns that string encoded as `UTF-8`. For conversions between any other encodings you have `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding`.