# convert_encoding not allowed in twig

Tags: twig, symfony-3.3

In order to convert my french html accents I try to change encoding by doing this in Twig :

```
{{ ddf.description | convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}
```

But here is the message I get :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from 'HTML-ENTITIES' to 'UTF-8' is not allowed").

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

"HTML-ENTITIES" is not an encoding.
It is a conversion function for special characters / accented encoding in (ISO ... UTF ...) to an equivalent in the same encoding or not depending on function and language.

Php htmlentities function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Here is the html entities table:
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Here is the list of encoding supported by iconv:
[how to get list of supported encodings by iconv library in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039232/how-to-get-list-of-supported-encodings-by-iconv-library-in-php)

You can try using the "| raw" twig filter or create your own.

[Unescape or html decode in Twig (PHP Templating)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453579/unescape-or-html-decode-in-twig-php-templating)

Answer (score 0):

Using automatic escaping should decode:

```
{% autoescape false %}
  {{ value|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

If you don't use `autoescape false`, it will not decode the html entities.  I used this for decoding `&#039;` to `'`.

Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works in Drupal 9.